# git merging newer branch into older branch?

Tags: git

Wow, I'm having a heck of a time with git.  Here is my situation.

1. **Master** -- all fine in good.  Most recent code in production.
2. **iss454** -- Originally pulled down remotely.  Then I somehow merged master in it, but lost all changes.  Unaware of this, I made changes and then pushed those changes.  iss454 now looks more like master with a handful of new changes.
3. After I pushed iss454 back up, I realized what I did.  Fudge!  So I went back and created a new branch for iss454 with the older (and good code) while in iss454:  ***git branch iss454-brian 867821ac***
4. **iss454-brian** -- This is now the original code from remote.
5. Once iss454-brian was created, I got nervous and created a new branch off of iss454 to make sure I didn't lose my new changes.  While in iss454, I did ***git checkout -b iss454-mike***
6. **iss454-mike** -- This is holding my new code that I need to apply on top of iss454-brian.

When I created iss454-brian, I verified that all the code that needs to be there is in fact there.

So now I need to take the changes in iss454-mike and apply them to iss454-brian.  Simple, right?  Yeah, not happening.

While in iss454-brian, I did ***git merge iss454-mike*** and git did its thing.  I thought great, it worked!  Until I went to look for the code that needed to be there.  Yeah missing.

iss454-brian now looks like iss454-mike but missing the code that I need.

What the heck is going on!

Comment: I'm surprised `iss454-mike` was created in step 5 - sounds like it already existed.  If you were going to create it, it would be `git checkout -b iss454-mike`...

Comment: Fixed this to reflect -b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have actually deleted the changes and commited those deletes on branch iss454-mike (also on iss454 which is what you first noticed).

When merging in changes from iss454-mike into iss454-brian you're deleting the changes again.

What you need to instead is reset iss454-brian to have the changes you need and then cherry-pick the changes from iss454 (or iss454-mike) that you are missing. Just find the SHA in the log for those.

iss454-brian should now contain what you need.

Or you can go into iss454 and do a rebase -i, find those weird deletes and just remove those commits. If you have already pushed them you need to think really hard about this since other clones might have the commits you are deleting/rewriting...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks much!  Cherry-picking originally came up during our discussion, but guess we couldn't really wrap our heads around everything going on.